# Change color of row based on time

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am making project monitoring package which is having five projects.Each project has five stages, it is defined by one row/line drawn horizontally.Time for each stage is also specified. If it goes beyond specified time line then the `color` of line should change to red.

Comment: Can you give us more code?